# Extra Story Cards for Firefly

Tags: firefly

Does anyone know of a place that compiles extra story cards for Firefly: The Board Game? I'm aware of the 'First Time in the Captain's Chair' official one, but I'd like to try some others too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few of them on BoardGameGeek.com, in the [Firefly - Variants forum](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/138161/firefly-game/forums/69?pageid=1&sort=hot).

Some people put "Story Card" or "Custom Story Card" in the title, which helps find them, others just put a title that describes what the story is.

Comment: Nice work, I had a quick look on BGG but couldn't find any!

Answer (score 3):

There is this one for 2 players from Board Game Geek and is an enjoyable, relatively short Firefly scenario.......

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1049020/slaying-dragon-co-op-story-card-two-players

Plus, this link leads to an extra 8 fan made story cards. They are well worth checking out as the base game only comes with 6 story cards....and those BGG Firefly fans are very creative. One of the scenarios is based on 'The Magnificent Seven', which,of course, is itself based on 'The Seven Samurai'.

http://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/107073/firefly-goalset-card-templates

Comment: Welcome to B&CG.SE! We generally look to have completed and descriptive answers, so I'd suggest making two edits to your posts. First, edit them into one answer so that all of your information is found grouped together. Second, rather than just providing links, add a description about what each of these links leads to and how it adds to the game. This will help the readers to better identify whether it is useful to them without needing to follow links. Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

The [official GF9 Firefly site also lists an online-only story card](http://www.fireflythegame.com/howtoplay/StoryCards.aspx#dnn_ctr465_HtmlModule_lblContent):

> Niska's Holiday ([pdf](http://flamesofwar.com/Portals/0/all_images/GF9/Firefly/Rulebooks/StoryCards/Firefly_Story_Card_Niska's_Holiday_v1.pdf))
>
> Expert card, recommended for Experienced Players. Not for the faint-hearted.
>
> "Do you know what a reputation is? It's people talking - gossip. It's not... To hold, touch it - you can't. Not from gossip. Now, I also have reputation. Not so pleasant." - Adelai Niska.
>
> This difficult Story Card is perfect for when you have mastered the flow of the game and are ready for an extra challenge. Most of Niska's Jobs are Illegal, Immoral or both, so you'll need a tough and unscrupulous crew behind you. A high fighting skill is a must, but you can't fight your way past every Misbehave card, so additional Skills and Gear certainly won't go amiss. Good luck!

[PDF download of the story card](http://flamesofwar.com/Portals/0/all_images/GF9/Firefly/Rulebooks/StoryCards/Firefly_Story_Card_Niska's_Holiday_v1.pdf)

Comment: Niska's Holiday was included in my (older) set.